# Difference between chronyd and ntpd

Tags: ntp, ntpd, chrony

What is the difference between `chronyd` and `ntpd`?

I know that `ntpd` can gradually adjust the time so that it can converge gradually to the the reference clock. Can this be done with `chrony`?

Comment: Please rephrase that in English. As for the difference, chronyd is an evolution of ntpd, and generally performs better and smoother both for frequent and high-accuracy clock drifts.

Comment: There is no one and only "ntpd", you have to be specific what server implementation you mean.

Comment: I corrected my English. About implementation, let will be RHEL (CentOS, Fedora).

Comment: @Dani_l do you have a reference for that claim, please? I've not previously heard of `chronyd` being more reliable than `ntpd` so I'd like to check out my options.

Comment: @roaima chronyd is not more reliable, but chronyd can adjust in situations where ntpd can't perform well (such as intermittent internet connections) and from experience can hold better accuracy where high precision is required (a clock with high drift that required at most 1 second diff at all times - ntpd had to be run with cron on a minute by minute basis (the best resolution cron provides), chronyd handled that better)

Answer (score 5):

This [site comparing chronyd vs ntpd vs openntpd](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/comparison.html) suggests that chronyd has more flexibility in configuring a slewing settings.

Comment: I just want to point out the comparison table may be biased. One should consider the source

Comment: Could be.  You could always provide other sources.

Answer (score 5):

The Red Hat documentation [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-configuring_ntp_using_the_chrony_suite) has a good comparison of Chrony and NTP and says "Chrony should be preferred for all systems except for the systems that are managed or monitored by tools that do not support chrony, or the systems that have a hardware reference clock which cannot be used with chrony."